# Tuning process exited unexpectedly.(DTAEngine)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database-tuning, database-tuning-advisor

I have tried to run the tuning advisor against multiple trace files and continually get the error "Tuning process exited unexpectedly.(DTAEngine).

The server is running SQL 2012 SP1 CU9. I have tried running both as a sysadmin and as a user with owner access to all databases on the server, but not sysadmin.

The only information I can find so far says to update to SP1 CU1, but I am already on CU9.

Can you point me to anything else I could try?

Comment: Same here. Running SQL 2012 SP2. Any info?

Comment: For me, the comment from @pmbAustin on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313151/database-engine-tuning-advisor-crashes-constantly did the trick. Do not include trace events from the stored procedure category.